# Need regex for note input in element

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex that will Match everything.

If the text is a word...it should mark the full word.

If the text is a number...it should mark the full number

It doenst matter what the value is of the text.
It should also include the linebreaks , the newlines and spaces.

Just everything that could be possible used in a text

Thanx in Advance

Comment: So, that's not what regular expressions are for. They're for regular languages, in which you need to identify and/or capture substrings within a larger string using a set of criteria.

Comment: Um.... `(.*)` should do that. Depending on what regex engine you're using (one provided by a language, something in an editor), you might need to set something so that it captures the newlines. But that doesn't make any sense. If you really want the **entire** string, you don't need a regex at all. What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: well actually it has something to do with xml. The xml file has an element called note. The note element can hold anything of text. First i thought of the xs:anytype. But then I will have an error on this <note>This is <b>very urgent</b> !</note> because the xml is seeing the "b" tag as an element. So i thought let me make an regex

Comment: You need to HTML encode the content before you embed it into an XML document, or something along those lines ... or you could Base64 encode it. That would work as well, but is probably unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: so you guys would go for the regex to ? Cause im not allowed to touch the xml file...I must make a scheme that matches

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about the following regex. This will match "everything."

```
.*
```

Comment: Thank you...! I had something similiar...but I wanted to have an second opinion! You just approved it! thanx